# VBA how do I build reference to a userform object property from a string?

Tags: excel, vba, string, userform

I have a button on my userform, lets call it `CommandButton2`. I have code that outputs at the very end a long value of 2 to refer directly to the button lets call that long `ButtonValue`.

Now if I wanted to loop through a number of buttons using the long value my first thought would be to do something like `CommandButton(ButtonValue).Caption = Value`, which obviously doesn't work.

I can use something like string concatenation to produce a string output `CommandButton2.Caption` but then how do I actually get that string to reference the UserForm object?

Am I even able to do such a thing and still make use of the `.Caption` object property? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work for you. Use `Controls` collection to set property of an object from variable.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ButtonValue As Long
    ButtonValue = 2
    Controls("CommandButton" & ButtonValue).Caption = ButtonValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, ```Controls``` is what I was missing there, thank you

Comment: You should use `Me.Controls`.